# Calculating a values in BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a database where I store weekly KPI from various retailers in a large table, and add a weekly snapshot to the database each week.

The values are various SKU/items, retailer name, quantity sold, quantity in retailer inventory, instock % (how many stores have sellable units), brand name, franchise name, etc, and each line of data has a snapshot of that monday's date.

From this, have been able to build quite a bit of useful information about item sales across retailers factoring in item availability (instock).

Since Covid hit, item availability has been a very large issue, and some of our brands are growing quite rapidly, so piecing together what sales might look like when all retailers are in stock is a big challenge.

Imagine an item is in 6 major retailers. I can split out sales history easily by retailer.

What I'd like to do is put together a metric that rolls up an overall sales # by adding up the average weekly sales (across maybe like last 4 or 8 values that meet the condition) by each of the 6 retailers ONLY when their store instock % was above say, 80 or 90%.

So I have an item selected, I have my 6 retailers broken out, and a value displayed for the average of the last 4 weeks that retailer was "in stock" sales, then added up to a "value" that's your hypothetical sales rate.

I've tried quite a few work arounds but can't seem to get anything that works.